# Ajax query not returning data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using jquery serialize and Ajax to capture form values and process them with Ajax using json as data Type, but no values are being returned. I have tried various ways to try and see why this is happening, but to no avail. There is no errors being returned in firebug or chrome. I would be grateful if someone could check my code and point out my error. Thanks

html code

```
<!--- Form to add box -->

<div id="boxaddform" style="display:none;">
    <div class="dialogTop_padd"></div>
        <form id="BA_boxform" name="BA_boxform" method="post">  

        <fieldset>
        <legend><span></span>Select Company</legend>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
        <div class="formMessage">Click again to open</div>
        <div class="fld_fld">

        <div>
        <label for="BA_customer">Company:</label><br />
        <select name="BA_customer" id="BA_customer">
        <option SELECTED VALUE="">Select a Company</option>
        <?php
        do {  
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row_Recordsetcust['customer']?>"><?php echo $row_Recordsetcust['customer']?></option>
        <?php

        } 
        while ($row_Recordsetcust = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordsetcust));
        $rows = mysql_num_rows($Recordsetcust);

        if($rows > 0)

        {
        mysql_data_seek($Recordsetcust, 0);
        $row_Recordsetcust = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordsetcust);
        }

        ?>
        </select>

        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <!--- displays the address and dept from the change function -->
        <div id="BA_dept"></div>
        <br />
        <div id="BA_address"></div>

            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="dialogTop_padd"></div>
        <!--- fieldset for service level -->
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Service Level</legend>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <div>
        <label for="BA_service">Service level:</label>
        <select name="BA_service" id="BA_service">
        <option SELECTED VALUE="">Select an option</option>
        <option value="Standard">Standard</option>
        <option value="Rapid">Rapid</option>
        </select><br />
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="dialogTop_padd"></div>

        <!--- fieldset for box # -->
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Box Details</legend>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <div>
        <label for="BA_box">Box#:</label><br />
        <input id="BA_box" name="BA_box" type="text" size="32" maxlength="128" value = "" /><br />
        </div>

        <div>
        <label for="BA_destdate">Destroy date:</label>
        <input id="BA_destdate" name="BA_destdate" type="text" size="32" maxlength="128" value = "" /><br />
        </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="dialogTop_padd"></div>
        <!--- fieldset for authorisation -->
        <fieldset>
        <legend>Authorisation</legend>
        <div class="spacer"></div>
        <div>
        <label for="BA_authorised">Requested By:</label>
        <input id="BA_authorised" name="BA_authorised" type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['kt_name_usr']; ?>"><br />
        </div>
        </fieldset>

        <!--- div to show callback result from ajax via dialog -->
        <div id="BA_addbox"></div>
        <br />
            <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="Submit Intake" />
            <input type="reset"  name="cancel" value="Clear Form" />
        <!--- buttons to submit form and reset form to default status -->
        <!-- <button id="BA_submit" class="submitbutton icon-right ui-state-default2 ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-plus"></span>Add Box</button>
        <button type="reset" id="BA_reset" class="resetbutton icon-right ui-state-default2 ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-plus"></span>Reset</button>
        --><br />

        </form>
    </div>
```

jquery code

```
$(function() {

    $("#BA_customer").live('change', function() { 
    if($(this).val()!="")
    $.get("/domain/admin/getDept.php?BA_customer=" + $(this).val(), function(data) {
    $("#BA_dept").html(data).show(); 
        });
    $.get("/domain/admin/getOptions.php?BA_customer=" + $(this).val(), function(data) {
    $("#BA_address").html(data).show(); 
    });

});
```

});

```
//Begin function to submit box intake form

$(function() { // Function to add box
$("#boxaddform").dialog({
 autoOpen: false,
 resizable: false,
 modal: true,
 title: 'Submit a box intake request',
 width: 550,
 height: 400,
   beforeclose: function (event, ui) {
   $("#BA_addbox").html("");
   $("#BA_dept").hide();
   $("#BA_address").hide();

   },
   close: function (event, ui) {
   //$("#BA_boxform").get(0).reset();
   $("#BA_addbox").html("");

   }
 });
});
$(function(){         
        $("#boxaddform").submit(function(){

         var formdata = $(this).serialize();

         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/domain/admin/requests/boxes/boxesadd.php",
           data: formdata,
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function(msg){
               //$("#confirm_department").hide();

               /*
               var $dialog = $('<div id="dialog"></div>')
               .html('Your intake was successfully submitted and will be viewable in the reporting area.<br /><br />Thank you.');
               $dialog.dialog({
               autoOpen: true,
               modal: true,
               title: 'Box intake submission successfull',
               width: 400,
               height: 200,
               draggable: false,
               resizable: false,
               buttons: {
               Close: function() {
               $( this ).dialog( "close" );
               }
               }
               });
               */
               //alert('You have succesfully submitted your ' + msg.company + ' report. Thank you.');
               //console.log(msg);
               //$("#BA_addbox").html("You may now close this window.");

               //$("#formImage .col_1 li").show();
               $("#BA_boxform").get(0).reset();
               $("#boxaddform").hide();
          }
       });
         return false;
     });
});

// End function to submit box intake form
```

php code

```
<?php

     $dept = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['BA_dept']);
     $company = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['BA_customer']);
     $address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['BA_address']);
     $service = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['BA_service']);
     $box = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['BA_box']);
     $destroydate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['BA_destdate']);
     $authorised = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['BA_authorised']);

     $form = array('dept'=>$dept, 'company'=>$company, 'address'=>$address, 'service'=>$service, 'box'=>$box, 'destroydate'=>$destroydate, 'authorised'=>$authorised);

     $result = json_encode($form);

     echo $result;

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to write some log on your server? I mean: are you sure the PHP script is receiving the query at all?

Comment: @Oscar When I look at the posted values in firebug, they are empty. They are not getting a s far as php. I just thought of that funny enough. This is what is in the html of boxesadd.php {"dept":"","company":"","address":"","service":"","box":"","destroydate":"","authorised":""}

Comment: I know it will sound silly, but could you add an `alert(formdata);` before the `$.ajax` call? Does it show what is expected?

Comment: I think you're attaching the event to the wrong object... Submit shoud be on forms, not divs... Can it be the problem?

Comment: @Oscar the alert is blank/empty

Comment: @Oscar didn't understand your comment re divs?

Comment: Excuseme, my english isn't as good as it should. I mean't that you're using `var formdata = $(this).serialize();`in a context where `$(this)` is `#boxaddform` (a div defined as `<div id="boxaddform" ...`). I'm not sure, but I think that `serialize` shoud be invoked on a `form`, something like  `$('#BA_boxform').serialize()`

Comment: @Oscar You are correct. I should have been refencing the form id not the div. Well spotted. However the dept and address values are not being sent. I am using a change event to input values into form. I have added change event code in my edit in my original code.

Comment: A FORM submit (even if it is send through an `AJAX` call) will only include FORM element's values (that is: `INPUTs`, `SELECTs` and `TEXTAREAs`), not the HTML text contained in a `DIV`. So, if you want it transferred, you shoud create, for example, a, `<input type="hidden"...` and set it's value throught the `change` event

Comment: @Oscar could you put something on fiddle to explain? thanks

Comment: I'll try later. Now it's impossible

Comment: K thanks. If you would like to put your comments as an answer, I shall gladly accept answer and up vote you. Many thanks

Comment: $('BA_boxform').serialize();//what you are getting from this or are sure you get the required you in var formdata

Comment: @AnkurSaxena I editted the answer. It lacked a '#'

Comment: @user1532468 : when you asked for a fiddle, what you wanted was to view how to put the value ina `hidden` control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are `serializing` a `DIV`, what is incorrect.

The solution would be to serialize only the `FORM` included in your `DIV` with a Javascript code like:

```
...
$(function(){         
    $("#boxaddform").submit(function(){

     var formdata = $('#BA_boxform').serialize();

     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/domain/admin/requests/boxes/boxesadd.php",
       data: formdata,
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(msg){
           ...
      }
   });
     return false;
 });
....
```

Also, remember that `serialize` will only care for `INPUT`, `SELECT`and `TEXTAREA` controls as a normal FORM submit would do (http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

Comment: great effort oscar but question is simple but represent in complex way